# Neo4j error caused by Lucene (Too many open files)

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I've just started evaluating Neo4j to see how well its fits our use case.
I'm using the embedded Java API to insert edges and nodes into a graph.
After creating around 5000 nodes I get the following error (using Neo4j 2.1.6 and 2.1.7 on OS X Yosemite)

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction

Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mihir.k/IdeaProjects/Turant/target/neo4j-hello-db/schema/label/lucene/_8zr.frq (Too many open files)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mihir.k/IdeaProjects/Turant/target/neo4j-hello-db/schema/label/lucene/_8zr.frq (Too many open files)
```

I've looked at numerous similar StackOverFlow questions and other related threads online. They all suggest increasing the max open files limit.
I've tried doing that.

These are my settings:

- kern.maxfiles: 65536
- kern.maxfilesperproc: 65536

However this hasn't fixed the error.

While the Neo4j code runs I tried using the `lsof|wc -l` command. The code always breaks when around 10000 files are open.

The following is the main class that deals with Neo4j:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v1_9.commands.True;
import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ast.False;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.UniqueFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexHits;

public class Neo4jDB implements  Serializable {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-hello-db-spark";
    IndexDefinition indexDefinition;

    private static GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory;
    public static GraphDatabaseService db;

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Life is a disease, sexually transmitted and irrevocably fatal. Stop coding and read some Neil Gaiman.");
    }



    public void startDbInstance() {
        db =new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    }

    public  Node createOrGetNode ( LabelsUser360 label , String key, String nodeName ,Map<String,Object> propertyMap)
    {
        System.out.println("Creating/Getting node");
        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() ) {
            Node node;

            if (db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, key, nodeName).iterator().hasNext()) {
                node = db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, key, nodeName).iterator().next();
            } else {
                node = db.createNode(label);
                node.setProperty(key, nodeName);

            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
                node.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            tx.success();
            return node;
        }

    }

    public  void createUniquenessConstraint(LabelsUser360 label , String property)
    {
        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() )
        {
            db.schema()
                    .constraintFor(label)
                    .assertPropertyIsUnique(property)
                    .create();
            tx.success();
        }
    }

    public void createOrUpdateRelationship(RelationshipsUser360 relationshipType ,Node startNode, Node endNode, Map<String,Object> propertyMap)
    {
        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() ) {
            if (startNode.hasRelationship(relationshipType, Direction.OUTGOING)) {
                Relationship relationship = startNode.getSingleRelationship(relationshipType, Direction.OUTGOING);
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
                    relationship.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                Relationship relationship = startNode.createRelationshipTo(endNode, relationshipType);
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
                    relationship.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            tx.success();
        }

    }

    public void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                db.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }

}
```

There is another Neo4jAdapter class that is used to implement domain specific logic. It uses the Neo4jDB class to do add/update nodes/properties/relationships

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.json.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class Neo4jAdapter implements Serializable {

    static Neo4jDB n4j = new Neo4jDB();
    public static GraphDatabaseService db = Neo4jDB.db ;

    public void begin() {
        n4j.startDbInstance();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {}



    public String graphPut(String jsonString) {

        System.out.println("graphput called");

        HashMap<String, Object> map = jsonToMap(jsonString); //Json deserializer

        Node startNode = n4j.createOrGetNode(...);
        Node endNode = n4j.createOrGetNode(...);

        propertyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        propertyMap.put(....);

        try (Transaction tx = Neo4jDB.db.beginTx()) {
            Relationship relationship = startNode.getSingleRelationship(...);
            if (relationship != null) {
                Integer currentCount = (Integer) relationship.getProperty("count");
                Integer updatedCount = currentCount + 1;
                propertyMap.put("count", updatedCount);
            } else {
                Integer updatedCount = 1;
                propertyMap.put("count", updatedCount);
            }
            tx.success();
        }


        n4j.createOrUpdateRelationship(RelationshipsUser360.BLAH, startNode, endNode, propertyMap);

                }
            }
        }
        return "Are you sponge worthy??";
    }
}
```

Finally, there is a Sprak App that calls the "graphput" method of the Neo4jAdapter class. The relevant code snippet is (the following is scala+spark code) :

```
val graphdb : Neo4jAdapter = new Neo4jAdapter()
graphdb.begin() 
linesEnriched.foreach(a=>graphdb.graphPutMap(a))
```

where 'a' is a json string and linesEnriched is a Spark RDD (basically a set of strings)

Comment: What does `ulimit -n` give? Is it the same 65K?

Comment: @Pang Thanks for the edit! Its my first question here.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you use to create the data? Perhaps something is leaking? Probably transactions.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Hey I've added all the relevant code. Let me know if any more info/context is required. I've been stuck on this for a really long time  now.